# Upgrade pykx version in kx provided jupyter notebook - https://edu.kx.com/user/

Tags: pykx

Default pykx version in kx provided jupyter notebook -https://edu.kx.com/user/ is 1.6.3.

**How can we update it to the latest version 2.1?**

When I'm tyrying to update it using pip install, below error is raised -

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (23.3)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pip/

$ pip install pykx==2.1
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pykx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pykx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pykx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pykx/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Filtered'))': /simple/pykx/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pykx==2.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pykx==2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the command on https://edu.kx.com/user/ itself it will not succeed as they are restricted sandbox environments. .i.e limited permissions, file system access, and no internet access to reach pip.

The best place to ask questions about the academy https://community.kx.com/

If you are on an unrestricted environment you can see latest versions on:

https://pypi.org/project/pykx/#history

```
pip install pykx==2.1.2
```

Or with Conda:

https://anaconda.org/kx/pykx/files

```
conda install pykx==2.1.1
```